# WordPress docker page is missing VIRTUAL_HOST variable

Tags: docker

According to many tutorials about WordPress & Docker, VIRTUAL_HOST is one variable of WordPress environment variables, but there is no mention of it in the [offcial WordPress page in hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress), and if this variable is not mentioned, I think it may be the case for other variables.

**I've searched the web a lot for such documentation but I didn't find**, and this is my question, Where can I find that documentation of VIRTUAL_HOST and other docker WordPress environment variables?

Comment: What would that do? Doesn't the WordPress docker image host a single WordPress instance? What would VIRTUAL_HOST be for?

Comment: @Rup, a single container of WordPress image serves s single instance of WordPress, but you can make more than one container and in this case, you need to add VIRTUAL_HOST variable to make the reverse proxy distinguish between the instances/containers.

Comment: OK, thanks. What is the reverse proxy that you're using? Wouldn't the virtual hosts need to be configured on the virtual proxy not on WordPress itself? (unless WordPress containers register themselves with the virtual proxy container, I suppose, but I don't you can do that in Docker?)